# What is the purpose of Guava's Verify?

Tags: java, guava

What is the purpose of [`com.google.common.base.Verify`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Verify.html) when we have [`com.google.common.base.Preconditions`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html)?

The `Verify` class looks nice but it has an `@Beta` annotation, should I use it?

Comment: You also have assertions. See Oracle's [Programming With Assertions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is semantic.  Verify is used to ensure that invariants don't change, that Code which has been engineered to do a certain thing is actually doing that thing.  In spirit:

```
int x = divide(10, 5);
Verify.verify(x == 2, "X should be 2");
```

Preconditions, on the other hand, are expected to fail when bad input is passed to a certain portion of the program, usually either from the user to the code, or from client code to code within another library.  In spirit:

```
public int divide(int x, int y) {
  Preconditions.checkArgument(y != 0, "Can't divide by 0!");
  return x / y;
}
```

As to whether you should use a @Beta class, that entirely depends on the scope and foreseeable lifetime of the application you are building, and, asked alone, would probably be flagged as a "Primarily Opinion-Based" question.

Comment: The @Beta question is answered on the Guava home page: "If your code is a library itself (i.e. it is used on the CLASSPATH of users outside your own control), you should not use beta APIs, unless you repackage them (e.g. using ProGuard)."

Answer (score 10):

Torquestomp's answer is wrong (though it may have been correct for its time, I don't know). See Guava's wiki entry: [Kinds of conditional failures](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ConditionalFailuresExplained).

**Precondition**

> A precondition check ensures that the caller of a public method has obeyed the requirements of the method's specification. For example, a sqrt function may accept only nonnegative arguments.

**Verification**

> A verification check is used when you lack high confidence that an API you consume will meet its (real or implied) specification. It's easiest to understand this type of check as "like an assertion in almost every way, but must remain enabled in production."

Don't worry too much though. From [Guava API docs](https://guava.dev/releases/32.1.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Verify.html):

> In some cases the differences [between Preconditions and Verify] can be subtle. When it's unclear which approach to use, **don't worry** too much about it; just pick something that seems reasonable and it will be fine.

Comment: To be fair, that's a very subtle difference versus the accepted answer. It would be useful if you explicitly called out where the accepted answer is wrong.

Comment: Whats wrong with the accepted answer? Accepted answer seems much more reasonable than this answer itself.